# JRuby rails server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jruby

I installed jruby and rails.
I chek It works.

```
jruby -v
jruby 1.7.12 (1.9.3p392) 2014-04-15 643e292 on Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 1.8.0_05-b13 +indy [Windows 7-amd64]
```

I created new app without error.
But when I tried to run "rails server" I got error:

```
"jruby.exe" -S "D:\Program Files\Java\jruby-1.7.12\bin\rails" server
Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory - "D:/Program Files/Java/jruby-  1.7.12/bin/jruby.exe"
 _exec_internal at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1774
        exec at file:/D:/Program Files/Java/jruby-  1.7.12/lib/jruby.jar!/jruby/kernel19/kernel.rb:25
exec_app_rails at D:/Program Files/Java/jruby-1.7.12/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/app_rails_loader.rb:37
        loop at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1501
  exec_app_rails at D:/Program Files/Java/jruby-1.7.12/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/app_rails_loader.rb:32
      (root) at D:/Program Files/Java/jruby-1.7.12/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/cli.rb:5
     require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1065
      (root) at D:/Program Files/Java/jruby-1.7.12/lib/ruby/shared/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:1
     require at D:/Program Files/Java/jruby-1.7.12/lib/ruby/shared/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:73
        load at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1081
      (root) at D:\Program Files\Java\jruby-1.7.12\bin\rails:23
```

Comment: what about with rails git master?

Answer (score 0):

I changed path to the jruby from D:/Program Files/Java/jruby-1.7.12 to D:\JRuby

Error was gone.